# Cannot get the updated the state value useState and UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I want to get the latest value of the state and use it inline style, but it firstly returns 0 values, then rendering updated the state. However, I cannot assign the values into the style.

```
const ImageCard = ({ image: { alt_description, urls } }) => {
  const [spans, setSpans] = useState(0);
  const imageRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => imageRef.current.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const height = imageRef.current.clientHeight;
    const spans = Math.ceil(height / 10);
    setSpans({ spans });
  }));

  return (
    <div style={{ gridRowEnd: `span ${spans}` }}>
      <img ref={imageRef} alt={alt_description} src={urls.regular} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

console output:

```
10 0
{spans: 15}
{spans: 33}
...
```

Comment: Does the parent of this component have `display: grid`?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Yes It has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not need `useEffect` for this. You can use the `onLoad` event of the img tag as follows:

```
const ImageCard = ({ image: { alt_description, urls } }) => {
  const [spans, setSpans] = useState(0);

  const imageLoaded = e => {
    const height = e.currentTarget.clientHeight;
    const spans = Math.ceil(height / 10);
    setSpans({ spans });
  };
  //Dont forget to remove this line
  console.log(spans);
  return (
    <div style={{ gridRowEnd: `span ${spans}` }}>
      <img onLoad={imageLoaded} alt={alt_description} src={urls.regular} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Working code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-platform-6sc67)